# Disabling restore down button in Qt MDIWindow

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way that I can disable the restore down buttons that appear at the top of the main window when I maximize my sub window in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
QWidget::setWindowFlags( Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint )
```

There is an example in the Qt Docs called Window Flags (or something similar).